# Authentication and Authorization in Blazor WebAssembly with Database First Approach

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-identity, blazor-webassembly

## Summary of my problem

My project is more complex but here is my problem at very basic level. I have a Blazor WebAssembly project where I do just basic CRUD operations.

I also have a small database and lets say I have two tables `Users` and `Roles`. What I do is to create their classes in Database-First fashion, by using `Scaffold-DbContext` and I run this command on the `Shared` project because I also want to reach to these classes from both `Server` and `Client` projects.

When I try to used `Individual User Accounts` on Authentication tab when creating a Blazor WebAssembly project, it creates the data models in the server. Which means I cannot access to my tables from `Client` Project. They need to be in `Shared`. Also it is Code-First based. I don't want to use migrations.

---

### What I tried

What I tried to do is to create an identical -almost- project with `Individual User Accounts` projects but my `Users` class inherits `IdentityUser` and my DbContext inherits `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` but problem starts here.

I cannot add `ApiAuthorization` package from NuGet because it says Shared project does not compatible with .NetStandard 2.1.

Also changing Shared project's standard didn't work.

---

#### Some Questions

- Can't I just add my users table on the Shared and use Identity from that table? (Since it's just a single table of rather larger database)
- Do I need two databases for this? One for Identity, one for rest of the application?
- Do I need to use Identity for Authentication & Authorization? What else can I use? Or Can I use a custom one where I can use it as I described earlier (Having models in Shared project)

---

My Goal

I want to authorize users with `[Authorize]` property. Since I cannot accomplish the registration, I cannot proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 DbContexts. The Identity tables (yours or ASP.NET) should not be part of the Shared or Client projects.

> I want to authorize users with [Authorize] property

The real authorization happens on the server, nothing in the client is safe. Have you looked at the complete (JWT based) implementation in the template?

> - Can't I just add my users table on the Shared and use Identity from that table? (Since it's just a single table of rather larger database)

No, Identity needs the base class. And your client app doesn't need (and shouldn't see) most of its properties.

> - Do I need two databases for this? One for Identity, one for rest of the application?

That is the best way. Note that you can have 2 DbContexts for 1 physical Db.

Link to the User wit a simple UserId (no Nav property) when needed.